# JavaFX TitledPane double border using css file

Tags: java, javafx

I have this code:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage){

    TitledPane titledPane = new TitledPane("TITLE", null);
    titledPane.setContent(new javafx.scene.control.TextArea("Batman"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(titledPane);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

style.css:

```
.titled-pane .title,
.titled-pane .content{
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-border-style: solid;
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
}
```

And the result is:

[image]

I don't understand why appear 2 borders.

If I remove `style.css` and use `setStyle`:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage){

    TitledPane titledPane = new TitledPane("TITLE", null);
    titledPane.setContent(new javafx.scene.control.TextArea("Batman"));

    Platform.runLater(() -> {

        titledPane.lookup(".title").setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;" +
                                                        "-fx-border-style: solid;" +
                                                        "-fx-border-color: black;" +
                                                        "-fx-border-width: 1px;");

        titledPane.lookup(".content").setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;" +
                                                        "-fx-border-style: solid;" +
                                                        "-fx-border-color: black;" +
                                                        "-fx-border-width: 1px;");

    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(titledPane);
    //scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

Now looks good:

[image]

Why using css file the result is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It was at css

```
.titled-pane .title,
.titled-pane .content{
   ...
}
```

This `.titled-pane .content` select all sub-nodes `content` of `titled-pane`, even sub-nodes of sub-nodes of `titled-pane`

Structure of this `titledPane.setContent(new javafx.scene.control.TextArea("Batman"));` is:

```
TitledPane -> title
           -> content = TextArea -> scroll-pane -> content
```

So my css change both `content`, which result in adding border to `scroll-pane -> content`

To modify only direct sub-nodes `titledpane -> title` and `titledpane-> title`, I need to use `>`:

```
.titled-pane > .title,
.titled-pane > .content{
   ...
}
```